# Ion trap computational basis measurement

Tags: measurement, ion-trap-quantum-computing

I'm studying the ion trap quantum computation and I'm wondering if a certain computational basis measurement, for example $|0\rangle$ state measurement, is possible in ion trap.

The fig.3 and 4 in the paper, https://www.nature.com/articles/nature18648, look like they measured each computational basis one by one, and they are saying in the method section that

> For the population distributions measured in Figs 3 and 4 and the reported algorithm fidelities, multi-qubit detection is performed by signal-averaging the populations of all 2n states over a few thousand experimental repetitions. In this way, detection and crosstalk errors are removed by decomposing the measurements into the known detector array response of all 32 possible qubit states.

Based on this statement, it seems that a specific computational basis measurement is possible but I wonder if it's possible and how.